# Little cot x problem

Tags: trigonometry

Recently started trig, but I'm not the best and I'm trying to understand everything.

I was told in class that: Cot x = 1/tan x = cos x / sin x

However, when I substitute a multiple of 90 into 1/tan x I get an undefined result. However, when I do the same to cos x / sin x I get 0...

Does this mean 1/tan x doesn't equal cos x / sin x?

Comment: $\tan x=\sin x/\cos x$ is not defined for $x=90$.

Comment: To add on to what @Bernard says, it is the same thing as saying $1/0$ is not defined, however, $0/1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

1/tan 90 = 1/(infinity) = 0.
So when u compute 1/tan(x) for odd multiples of 90 u will get an expression of a kind 1/(infinity) which will be equal to zero....since any no. divided by infinity is 0 (except infinity itself)...so the results u get from 1/tanx and cosx/sinx are not contradictory....u get the same answer from both.